# TestLink error when test fails

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, testlink

Im writing tests in selenium webdriver, in java and i have it integrated with testlink using TestNG. So when i run a test and the run is correct, it saves correctly in testlink. But when the test fails the following error appear on the test:

testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException: The required parameter status was not provided by the caller.

this is my test method:

```
@Parameters({"nombreBuild", "nombrePlan", "nomTL_validacionCantidadMensajes"})
    @Test
    public void validarMensajes(String nombreBuild, String nombrePlan, String nomTL_validacionCantidadMensajes) throws Exception {
        String resultado = null;
        String nota = null;
        boolean test;
        try{
            homePage = new HomePageAcquirer(driver);
            homePage.navigateToFraudMonitor();
            fraud = new FraudMonitorPageAcquirer(driver);
            test = fraud.validarCantidadMensajes();
            Assert.assertTrue(test);
            if(test){
                resultado = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED;
            }else {
                nota = fraud.getError();
                System.out.println(nota);
                resultado = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_FAILED;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            resultado = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_FAILED;
            nota = fraud.getError();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            ResultadoExecucao.reportTestCaseResult(PROJETO, nombrePlan, nomTL_validacionCantidadMensajes, nombreBuild, nota, resultado);
        }
    }
```

The xml is fine beacuse when the test passes it works.

And the testlink method to set the values.

```
 public static void reportTestCaseResult(String projetoTeste, String planoTeste, String casoTeste, String nomeBuild, String nota, String resultado) throws TestLinkAPIException {
    TestLinkAPIClient testlinkAPIClient = new TestLinkAPIClient(DEVKEY, URL);
    testlinkAPIClient.reportTestCaseResult(projetoTeste, planoTeste, casoTeste, nomeBuild, nota, resultado);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that you will never get to the else block of this condition

```
Assert.assertTrue(test);
if(test){
    resultado = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED;
} else {
    //
}
```

When Asser fails, new `AssertionError` occurs so you never make it even to the if condition. You also can't catch this error because `Exception` derives from `Throwable` and `Error` too. So you basically can remove the condition and try to catch `Error` - which is not really best practice but it will work. The best thing to use in these situations is [listener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging) but I am not sure how this works with `@Parameters`. However, you can always do it like this

```
try{
    Assert.assertTrue(test);
    resultado = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED;
} catch (AsertionError e){
     resultado = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_FAILED;
     nota = fraud.getError();
     e.printStackTrace();
 }finally{
     ResultadoExecucao.reportTestCaseResult(PROJETO, nombrePlan, nomTL_validacionCantidadMensajes, nombreBuild, nota, resultado);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks on the reply its perfect, going to look into the Listener.

Comment: Based on your profile - it's nice if you upvote or accept answer when you find it useful, this will motivate people to give you some answers

Comment: Sorry i didnt realize i didnt accept the answer, thanks on leting me know that.

Comment: That's ok, I didn't know that too some time ago:-)I am glad it helped you